# How to print some column by for loop in R

Tags: r

I've some table in R (my_df) with the columns: "name", "city", country".

I also have a vector that holds some of the columns names:

```
name_vec = c("city", "country")
```

I want to print all the current column in name_vec by for loop:

```
for (i in name_vec ){
print(my_df$i)
}
```

Now it doesn't work well, How can I fix it?

Important - I want to use just in my variable "i" - without any number or string

TY

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let suppose we have this `data.frame`

```
# Define a data.frame
  df <- data.frame(city=c("Madrid", "Paris", "London", "Barcelona"),
                   country=c("SPA", "FRA", "UK", "SPA"))
# Column names
  c.name <- c("city", "country")
```

You can use the following code in order to get each column

```
# Print each column
  for (i in 1:length(c.name)){
    print(df[,c.name[i]])
  }


# What you get . . . 
  [1] "Madrid"    "Paris"     "London"    "Barcelona"
  [1] "SPA" "FRA" "UK"  "SPA"
```